# How to login with a non-login shell user?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, login

How do I login as a non-login shell user such as the `apache` user?

If I run `sudo su - apache` I get:

> This account is currently not available.

And in /etc/passwd I have:

> apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-u <username>` with the `-s` option to launch an interactive shell. e.g. `sudo -u apache -s` then test with `whoami`.

From `man sudo`:

> **-s [command]**
>
> The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in
> the password database.  If a command
> is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  **If no command is specified, an interactive
> shell is executed.**

> **-u user**
>
> **The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user other than root.**  To specify a uid instead of a user
> name, #uid.  When running commands
> as a uid, many shells require that the `#' be escaped with a backslash (`').  Security policies may restrict uids to those
> listed in the password database.
> The sudoers policy allows uids that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw option is not set.  Other
> security policies may not support this.